# Why doesn't Math.Round/Floor/Ceiling return long or int?

Tags: c#, .net

*Every* time I use `Math.Round/Floor/Ceiling` I always cast to `int` (or perhaps `long` if necessary). Why exactly do they return `double` if it's always returning an integer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The result might not fit into an int (or a long). The range of a double is much greater.

Approximate range of double: ±5.0 × 10<sup>−324</sup> to ±1.7 × 10<sup>308</sup>

[(Source)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx)

Comment: They said or long in the question.

Comment: The point remains the same.  A `double` can be larger than 9223372036854775807.

Comment: I figured this would be the reason but just wanted to make sure. Obviously rounding to an integer *bigger* than a long is rare for *most applications*, Microsoft still had to implement it to make sense mathematically. Thanks!

Comment: @dan04: True, but only doubles below 2^52 can have a non-zero fractional part, so the function is generally only useful in cases where the dynamic range of the number is known to be below that.  I think a bigger issue is that code wanting to turn a floating-point type into a rounded integer type may just as likely want an `Int32` as `Int64`, and there's no sensible way to use overloading to convey that.  Java overloads `round(double)` to return `long`, but `round(float)` to return `int`, with the curious effect that calling `round` on a `long` which exceeds 2^31 will peg it...

Comment: ...to the maximum `int` value, and calling it on other `long` values over 16777216 will yield a result rounded to the nearest `float`.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with Mark's answer that the result might not fit in a `long`, but you might wonder: what if C# had a much longer `long` type?  Well, here's what happens in Python with it's arbitary-length integers:

```
>>> round(1.23e45)
1229999999999999973814869011019624571608236032
```

Most of the digits are "noise" from the floating-point rounding error.  Perhaps part of the motivation for `Round`/`Floor`/`Ceiling` returning `double` in C# was to avoid the illusion of false precision.

An alternative explanation is that the .NET `Math` module uses code written in C, in which [floor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x39715t6%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [ceil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/atdhw2dx.aspx) return floating-point types.

Answer (score 2):

Range arguments aside, none of these answers addresses what, to me, is a fundamental problem with returning a floating point number when you really want an exact integer.  It seems to me that the calculated floating point number could be less than or greater than the desired integer by a small round off error, so the cast operation could create an off by one error. I would think that, instead of casting, you need to apply an integer (not double) round-nearest function to the double result of `floor()`.  Or else write your own code. The C library versions of `floor()` and `ceil()` are very slow anyway.

Is this true, or am I missing something?  There is something about an exact representation of integers in an IEEE floating point standard, but I am not sure whether or not this makes the cast safe.

I would rather have range checking in the function (if it is needed to avoid overflow) and return a long. For my own private code, I can skip the range checking. I have been doing this:

```
long int_floor(double x)
{
    double remainder;
    long truncate;
    truncate = (long) x;        // rounds down if + x, up if negative x
    remainder = x - truncate;   // normally + for + x, - for - x
    //....Adjust down (toward -infinity) for negative x, negative remainder
    if (remainder < 0 && x < 0)
        return truncate - 1;
    else
        return truncate;
}
```

Counterparts exist for `ceil()` and `round()` with different considerations for negative and positive numbers.

Comment: If what one wants is to map floating-point values to things that can be given to code that requires `Int32` or `Int64`, having methods to perform such a mapping directly using round-to-nearest-even or round-toward-negative-infinity would be helpful.

Comment: A round-to-integer operation on floats cannot create a rounding error that did not exist presently, since the integer above the largest number with a fractional part is precisely representable.

Answer (score -2):

There is no reason given on the docs that I could find. My best guess is that if you are working with doubles, chances are you would want any operations on doubles to return a double. Rounding it to cast to an int was deemed by the language designer less common then rounding and keeping as a double.

You could write your own method that cast it to an int for you in about 2 lines of code, and much less work than posting a question on stack overflow...

Comment: Sure it's trivial to write your own, but Mark's answer provides insight. StackOverflow is not always about the 'how', I also like it for the 'why' :)

Comment: -1 - I know *how*, I'm wondering *why*. Your answer doesn't even make sense.