# why math.Ceiling (double a) not return int directly?

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, base-class-library

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't Math.Round/Floor/Ceiling return long or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481696/why-doesnt-math-round-floor-ceiling-return-long-or-int)

msdn defined this method:Returns the smallest **integer** greater than or equal to the specified double-precision floating-point number.

but in fact,it is

```
public static double Ceiling (
    double a
)
```

why not return int directly? what does microsoft think of ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It's because the range of a `double` (±5.0 × 10<sup>−324</sup> to ±1.7 × 10<sup>308</sup>) is much greater than the range of an `int` (-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647). If the return type were `int` many possible inputs would fail. For example [`Math.Ceiling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48.aspx) might be forced to throw an [`OverflowException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.overflowexception.aspx) in a [checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) context, or it might even return an incorrect result in an unchecked context. This is undesirable behaviour.

Also some special values such as [`NaN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan.aspx) and [`PositiveInfinity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.positiveinfinity.aspx) can be returned by this method. This is only possible if the return type is `double`.

If you believe that the result will fit into an int, you can add an explicit cast:

```
int result = (int)Math.Ceiling(a);
```

Comment: And of course, if you do an explicit cast like that example, if the value *doesn't* fit, the runtime will throw a fit (and you get the exception to deal with).

Comment: It's silly really: doubles can only reliably store ~7-8 significant figures anyway, so you wouldn't be able to Round anything higher than `2147483648`.

Comment: @ChrisBurt-Brown: A `double` can hold every multiple of one-half up to 2^52, which is considerably larger than the 2^31 range of `Int32` (but smaller than the 2^63 range of an `Int64`).

Comment: Note that casting to an `int` will truncate, so if your decimal is rendered as 1.9999998675 you might end up with 1. `Convert.ToInt32()` will round.

Comment: @IronSean Whoa, so .Cieling is almost guaranteed to return a value slightly off of a whole number since it returns a double. So everywhere I've seen a (int) cast used it's probably returning an incorrect value 50% of the time?